# Basic Angular CRUD service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble setting up a CRUD service that I can call to set and get a particular value between 2 components...

> string is not assignable to type Subject

```
export class ChangeService {
  colour: Subject<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.colour = new Subject();
  }

  changeColour(colour: string) {
    // this is where the TS error is thrown
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  getColour(): Observable<any> {
    return this.colour;
  }

}
```

Comment: That error message is very clear, what do you not understand about it? `Subject<string>` and `string` are two different types

Comment: `this.colour.next(colour)` instead of `this.colour = colour`

Comment: Plus there is no need for constructor instantiation: `colour: new Subject<string>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `BehaviorSubject` and calling the `next` method on it instead.

```
export class ChangeService {
  colour: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  changeColour(colour: string) {
    this.colour.next(colour);
  }

}
```

To get the color you can simply subscribe to `colour` in your Component Class.

```
color;
constructor(private changeService: ChangeService) {}

this.changeService.colour.subscribe(color => this.color = color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `BehaviorSubject` and calling the `next` method on it instead.

```
export class ChangeService {
  colour: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  changeColour(colour: string) {
    this.colour.next(colour);
  }

}

// To get the color you can simply subscribe to `colour`
```